# Display image using json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

All work to **fetch image src from mysql**, moving to js file till html work fine but I'm wondering, why the (pic) **selector does not display my image on the page.**

This is my php file which fetch all images from mysql database related to marker selected .

[This is the result shown in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6kHc.jpg)

```
    <?php
    $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = 'maalem';


    $sql2 = "SELECT img FROM image WHERE L_ID=:id";
    try {
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $con->query('SET NAMES utf8');
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql2);  
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $_GET["L_ID"]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $img = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
        $con = null;
        echo '{"pics":'. json_encode($img) .'}'; 
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
    ?>

//this is the javascript file 



    $('#detailsPage').live('pageshow', function (event) {
    var id = getUrlVars()["L_ID"];
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getmarker.php?L_ID=' + id, displayimg);
    });


    function displayimg(data) {
     var imgs = data.pics;
     console.log(imgs);
    $('#pic').append('<img src="' + imgs.img + '"width=160 height=160/>');

    $('#actionList').listview('refresh');

     }


    function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [],
    hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
     }

//HTML file 

   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="detailsPage" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1 id="Name"></h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content"> 


                <div id="markerDetails">
                    <h2> الوصف </h2>
                    <p id="Dec"></p>
                    <div id="pic"></div>
                </div>



            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `<img id="pic"/>` you have defined an img with id `pic`
and in this line `$('#pic').text('<img src="' + imgs.img + '"width=160 height=160/>');` you are trying to get element by `pic` and insert a text, which is incorrect.

`<div id="pic"></div>` this will do the work for you, insert img tags inside this div usinf `innerHTML` (javascript) or `.html()` (jQuery)

Comment: even when i change it , imgs.img not take the object (src) in the browser @MohdAsimSuhail

Comment: `console.log(imgs);`  `imgs` variable is an array, you should iterate on `imgs` array to append in div. `for(var j=0;j<imgs.length;j++){$('#pic').append('<img src="' + imgs[j].img + '"width=160 height=160/>');}`

Comment: Glad could help you, if you are satisfied with the answer then you can upvote and accept the answer to help others if they face the same problem. :)